# Recursive function parameters

Tags: recursion, f#, functional-programming

I made a simple recursive function, and expected it to work (but it doesn't):

```
open System
open System.Threading

let f =
    let r = Random()
    let rec d =
        printfn "%d" (r.Next())
        Thread.Sleep(1000)
        d
    d
f
```

With the help of Intellisense I ended up with the following working function (but without understanding why previous function didn't work):

```
open System
open System.Threading

let f : unit =
    let r = Random()
    let rec d() =
        printfn "%d" (r.Next())
        Thread.Sleep(1000)
        d()
    d()
f
```

So why do I need to explicitly state `unit` and `()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first version, you declared a recursive object (`let rec d`), or a value. You're saying that the `d` object is recursive, but how an object could be recursive? How does it call itself? Of course, this doesn't make sense.

It's not possible to use recursive objects in F# and this is the reason why your first version doesn't work.

In the second version, you declared a recursive function (`let rec d()`). Adding `()`, you're explicitly stating that `d` is a function.
Furthermore you explicitly stated, with `unit`, that the function `f` (called just once) will not return anything, or, at least, you're saying that `f` will return a value of a not specific type. In F#, even the simplest functions must always return a value.

In your case, F# will try to infer the type that `f` will return. Because there's no specific type annotation and your `f` is not doing something (like a calculation) that will return a specific value using a specific type, the F# compiler will assign a generic return type to `f`, but your code is still ambiguous and you have to specify the `unit` type (the simplest type that a F# function could return) to be more specific.

The value restriction error is related indeed to F#'s powerful type inference. Please have a look at [this interesting article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mulambda/2010/05/01/finer-points-of-f-value-restriction/) about this error.

Answer (score 2):

In your first attempt, you define not a function, but a *value*. The value `d` is defined in terms of itself - that is, in order to know what `d` is, you need to first know what `d` is. No wonder it doesn't work!

To make this a bit more clear, I will point out that your definition is of the same kind as this:

```
let x = x
```

Would you expect this to work?

In your second attempt, you gave `d` a *parameter*. It is the parameter that made it a *function* and not a value. Compare:

```
let rec x() = x()
```

This will still cause a stack overflow when executed, but at least it will compile: it's a function that unconditionally calls itself.

You didn't have to give it specifically a `unit` parameter, any parameter would do. You could have made it a number, a string, or even a generic type. It's just that `unit` is the simplest option when you don't care what it is.

And you didn't actually need to annotate `f` with a type. That was an extraneous step.

In conclusion, I'd like to point out that even in your second code block, `f` is still a *value*, not a function. In practical terms it means that the code inside `f` will be executed just once, when `f` is defined, and not every time you mention `f` as part of some other expression, which is apparently what you intuitively expect.

Comment: `And you didn't actually need to annotate f with a type. That was an extraneous step.` But without this extraneous step (if all else is correct), it still throws an error: Value restriction. The value 'f' has been inferred to have generic type val f : '_a >Either define 'f' as a simple data term, make it a function with explicit arguments or, if you do not intend for it to be generic, add a type annotation.

Comment: You're right, I forgot about value restriction. But if you make `f` a function, then that problem will disappear anyway.

Comment: If you make `f()` and then call it (all else being correct), it still throws this `Value restriction` exception. So it seems the only way out is to state `unit` explicitly. But still thanks for answers, they are all really helpful.